# Streaming a complex array from nodejs server as a response to http post

Tags: node.js, express, http, stream

I'll try to keep it simple:

An example of what I currently have

```js
router.post('/handleMail', async (req, res, next) => {
    var x = [{a:{b:"b"}, c:{ok:"ok}] // just imagine this is convoluted array containing objects.
    res.json({body: x})
})
```

So lets say variable "x" is HUGE, containing some base64 encoded string etc.

When I try to simply return it like this the process usually stalls.

1. Will streaming this as a response help this?
2. How would I go about streaming it to "res" in this case?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a library like [json-stream-stringify](https://github.com/Faleij/json-stream-stringify) that creates a readable stream from your json that you can pipe into the express response-object:

```
const JsonStreamStringify = require('json-stream-stringify');

router.post('/handleMail', async (req, res, next) => {
    const jsonObject = [{a:{b:"b"}, c:{ok:"ok}];
    new JsonStreamStringify(jsonObject ).pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I ended up using exactly, but I will have to change the architecture anyway, its not a good idea to pass big things over microservices it seems. For anyone curious I'll use some shared storage and pass a reference. thanks again.